# child#2 div adjusting to available vertical space, depending on child#1's height

Tags: html, css, height, fluid

I'd like to do the following with HTML5 / CSS3  (full browser compliance would be nice, but not totally necessary - I'm testing with firefox 4b12, safari and chrome so far):

I have the following html structure:

```
<div id=contentwrapper>
  <aside>  
   <div id=child1></div>
   <div id=child2></div>
  </aside>
  (<div id=maincontent></div>)
</div>
```

What I want to do is the following:

contentwrapper is set position fixed, top 20, bottom 20px (= use all space between a fixed header and footer).

aside is set to 100% height (use all space of content wrapper!)

child1 has variable content (potentially changed by CSS- or DOM manipulation by user interaction), so it's height is set to auto to adjust it's height accordingly.

child2 has also variable content. but I want this div to use all available vertical space that is left within the aside and that is not occupied by child1. If it's content needs more space, there is a overflow:auto to make a scrollbar if necessary.

The whole column is followed by a main content area that is floated right. this should not be relevant to my problem though.

what I tried so far:

I can't set child2's height to auto or 100% or a fixed value (could be to large, no scrollbar, don't know users window height, ...).

I can't use position:fixed and top+bottom values, as this does not looks at child1, but renders relatively to aside.

I can't use display:table, as the elements do have borders/formattings that don't apply to table cells.

I hope you understand the problem, and maybe have a smart solution ...

Edit: here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: http://www.gestaltungssache.at/stuff/beschreibungproblem.png]

In view 1 you can see what happens at the moment when viewport is high enough.

In view 2, there is not enough space, and child2 slides down under the footer ...

what I'd like is to that child2 takes all it can get in height, but scrolls its content.

thanks for your help

sebastian

Comment: When your description has that many words, it's a good idea to draw a picture. It might also be useful to create an example of what you have so far using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: i have added a link to a screenshot.  tried jsfiddle, but it's difficult to separate all unnecessary code and get it run there ...

Answer (score 0):

If you set child1 to `float:left` and child2 to `height:100%` and both of them to `width:100%` I think that will achieve the effect you're after.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p44Yv/)?

Comment: thanks - that's an idea i haven't come up with yet ... it "almost" works. but when i add a overflow-y:scroll to child2, it is moved to the right of child1, not below anymore.  to come around this, if i add a float:left to child2 too, height of child2 is the full height of aside again, instead of only the rest ...

Comment: @sebastian Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/p44Yv/34/. I've put a wrapper `DIV` around the child which should scroll, and given it a min-height at which the scroll bar should appear.